# Is it possible to get both pdf bookmarks and hyperref for index links?

Tags: hyperref, indexing, bookmarks

I loaded both the `bookmark` and `hyperref` package, but when I have them both the index links don't work. When I comment out the `bookmark` package the index links work, but the bookmarks don't. How do I fix this?

Minimal Not Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bookmark} % Used for pdf bookmarks
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Used for index
\usepackage{hyperref} % Used for index links

\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \section{foo}
    \lipsum[1]
    \index{foo}
    \section{bar}
    \index{bar}
    \lipsum[2]

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load bookmark after imakeidx, also you don't have to load hyperref, bookmark will do it. *If* you want to load hyperref to pass an option do it before bookmark (but again after imakeidx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bookmark` package is designed to fix a few features of `hyperref`; although the documentation doesn't tell it explicitly, it should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Actually, `bookmark` loads `hyperref` itself, if not already done. Since `hyperref` changes the meaning of `\index`, it should be loaded later than `imakeidx` for hyperlinks to be added to index entries.

So the correct loading order is

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know the loading order of packaged mattered! Thanks for the explanation!